# Mostrar en mi web comentarios y puntuaciones de páginas como Booking o Tripadvisor

Tags: javascript, html, css

¿Es posible insertar en mi página web un botón que muestre a mis usuarios las puntuaciones y comentarios que dan a mi negocio los usuarios de Tripadvisor, Booking, Google...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes agregar algunos widgets que te ofrecen las paginas oficiales de las herramientas que has expuesto.

**Tripadvisor**
https://www.tripadvisor.com.mx/Widgets

**Google**
https://developers.google.com/+/web/